# In Firebase functions, how to clean up database refs after use?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I remove `ref` after my function is finished running? Is it necessary? I want my function to run as quickly as possible, and don't want "things" piling up.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/path/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
   const ref = event.data.adminRef.root.child('something').child(event.params.uid);

   return ref.transaction(current => {
      if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
         return _.toInteger(current) + _.toInteger(_.get(data, 'value', 0));
      }
   }).then(() => {
      return null; // Avoid "Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
    });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. Do you want to remove the data at `ref` from the database after the function is done?

Comment: No, I meant avoid open "connections" :) But I guess thats not a problem.

What you're referring to might be some sort of queue? Something like 

`return ref.set(data).then(() => {
      return event.data.ref.remove();
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DatabaseReference` is nothing you can "remove". It is just a pointer to a location in your database. The documentation has a page for it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference

The only thing you can remove/detach is a callback you set with `ref.on(...)`, with `ref.off(...)`, but there is no callback in your code and I think that `ref.once()` should get the job done most of the time in Functions.

To be clear: `ref.transactions()`'s do not have to be detached, they just run once, i.e. there is no callback. Same for `ref.set()` and `ref.once()`.

Comment: @RemiSture I am glad, my answer solved your question! You can also accept my answer, so other know it has been answered and does not appear as "unanswered" :)

Comment: I tried `ref.on()` and `ref.off()` but it still listens while I change value.